# Heda - hed:too many soql queries: 201

Tags: apex, soql, managed-package

I have a managed package ("Heda") - SF package for university usage.

when I'm upserting many contacts (1000 to be precise) it throws me an error:

System.LimitException: hed:Too many SOQL queries: 201.

I'm running only 3 SOQL queries in my process and I can see it in the debugging at the end of my code

```
(System.debug('getQueries() -> ' + Limits.getQueries());)
```

(I'm running that in qeueuable apex so It gives me more queries to spend).

I can't see the code under the hood that "HEDA" package using because its a managed package.

Anyone here had a similar issue with this package or another and have advice?

Many many Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid the only option is to contact a developer of this package and ask why does that occur. Or insert accounts in smaller chunks

Comment: Thank you.. I did insert small chunks because of this, but I will contact the package developer.
I will mark it as the best answer if you will write one, to close this question.